# Python request returns 404 while curl returns the pdf stream

Tags: python, pdf, curl

I am new to python and trying out sample requests and response. Currently referring the [documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/). I'd like to get a pdf response and write it to my local directory. Tried curl to [this](http://www.analysis.im/uploads/seminar/pdf-sample.pdf) and returned the stream but using requests returned 404. The page does not require any session and therefore called `requests.get(url)`. Am I missing something with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The webserver is allowing curl's user agent, but blocking the one that requests uses:

```
In [7]: import requests

In [8]: url = 'http://www.analysis.im/uploads/seminar/pdf-sample.pdf'

In [9]: requests.get(url)
Out[9]: <Response [404]>

In [10]: requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'firefox'})
Out[10]: <Response [200]>
```

Comment: You can specify user agent header using requests thought

Comment: @DavidD.: Yeah, but the default one (for me) is `python-requests/2.6.0 CPython/2.7.9 Darwin/14.3.0`. The webserver doesn't like it.